# JavaScript convert array to JSON format

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I have an array like

```
["categories", 1, "categories", 2, "categories", 3]
```

I want to convert this array to JSON format like

```
{"categories":1,"categories":2, "categories":3}
```

Comment: you cant have same property name multiple times in an object `{"categories":1,"categories":2, "categories":3}` => `{"categories":3}`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Anyone please suggest me the best idea to send multiple checkbox value through ajax?

Comment: What you can probably aim for is `{"categories": [1,2,3]}`

Comment: Fore serializing a form use `serialize()` or `serializeArray()`

Comment: Thank You Pranav C Balan and  Rajesh Yogeshwar. This Now I am going through {"categories": [1,2,3]}. And this is working. Thank You again.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert an array into JSON with:

```
var a = ["categories", 1, "categories", 2, "categories", 3];
var json = JSON.stringify(a);
// json will be: "["categories",1,"categories",2,"categories",3]"
```

The JSON string you have in your question is not an array, it is an object. And as Pranav pointed out in his comment, it is an invalid object notation, because the properties of an object have to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

In such case We will have to go through `{"categories": [1,2,3]}`. for this we have to create a array of values and create a JSON data `{"categories": [1,2,3]}`.

This solves the problem to post multiple values of same field like checkbox through ajax.

Answer (score 0):

if you means this

`["categories1", 1, "categories2", 2, "categories3", 3]`

each key is different, then you can go with

```
var a = ["categories1", 1, "categories2", 2, "categories2", 3],
    b = {}, len = a.length;

for(i=0; i<len; i+=2){
    var key = a[i], val = a[i+1];
    b[key] = val
}

// b should be {"categories1":1,"categories2":2, "categories3":3}
```

if not, just like @Pranav C Balan said, you can't have three identical keys in one object, they will simply override the previous ones;

you might also need this [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#object) method, really handy

```
_.object(['moe', 'larry', 'curly'], [30, 40, 50]);
=> {moe: 30, larry: 40, curly: 50}

_.object([['moe', 30], ['larry', 40], ['curly', 50]]);
=> {moe: 30, larry: 40, curly: 50}
```